# Does there exist a Detect Deity Spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does there exist a spell (or other method) that allows the magical divination of a character's patron deity? I'll accept official or third-party solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick google search for

```
site:http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells deity
site:http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells deity
```

Reveals all spells in the Pathfinder SRD for both Paizo and third party publications that contain the word "deity".

The best match seems to be [*Reveal Heretic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/radiance-house/reveal-heretic), which is a cleric 2, inquisitor 2, paladin 2 spell by Radiance House, published in Pact Magic Unbound, Vol. 1.

> This spell determines to what degree the touched creature's religious views are similar or contrary to your own. If the creature fails its saving throw, you instantly learn the creature's ethos (whether it is chaotic, lawful, or neutral), its morality (whether it is evil, good, or neutral), **its patron deity (if any)**, and the name of any religious organizations it belongs to.

Emphasis mine

Comment: Someone should explain the definition of *heretic* to Radiance House, methinks.

Comment: Why do I have a feeling most deities would not fail a Will save? =)

Comment: @KRyan Perhaps "Reveal Infidel" didn't pass their legal/PR team!

Answer (score 5):

If the character is a cleric, then a DC 10 knowledge (religion) check can identify the deity based on her holy symbol if it's a common deity, and DC 20 for an obscure deity. It's not a spell or magical divination, and it only works on characters that choose to wear a holy symbol, but it's in the [knowledge table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge).

Comment: Far more importantly than not working on those lacking a holy symbol, it gives false results on anyone carrying a false flag.